How can I run a function at the end of a pipe?
This code makes a sentence from two different columns in a data frame
library(dplyr); library(tibble); library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) -> 
  df

paste0(df$car, " (", df$mpg, ")", collapse = ", ")

# "Mazda RX4 Wag (21), Hornet Sportabout (18.7), Merc 280 (19.2), Dodge Challenger (15.5), Merc 450SLC (15.2)"

But instead of having paste0(df$car, " (", df$mpg, ")", collapse = ", ") run on a standalone line, how can I get it to run at end of pipe like the below (which throws an error as written):
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  paste0(df$car, " (", df$mpg, ")", collapse = ", ")


with() would work for this:
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %>% 
  with(paste0(car, " (", mpg, ")", collapse = ","))

Another possibility would be to end the pipe with:
... %>% 
   mutate(word = glue("{car} ({mpg})")) %>% 
   pull(word) %>% 
   paste0(collapse =", ")


Here a base R approach.
sprintf('%s (%s)', rownames(mtcars), mtcars$mpg) |>
  sample(5) |> 
  toString()
# [1] "Chrysler Imperial (14.7), Hornet Sportabout (18.7), Mazda RX4 (21), Pontiac Firebird (19.2), Merc 280 (19.2)"

or
transform(mtcars, car=rownames(mtcars)) |> 
    subset(car %in% sample(car, 5)) |> 
    with(sprintf('%s (%s)', car, mpg)) |> 
    toString()
# [1] "Mazda RX4 (21), Hornet Sportabout (18.7), Merc 280 (19.2), Chrysler Imperial (14.7), Pontiac Firebird (19.2)"


glue::glue_data() is a concise solution built specifically for this use case:
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(glue)
library(stringr)

mtcars |> 
  rownames_to_column("car") |> 
  sample_n(5) |> 
  glue_data("{car} ({mpg})") |> 
  str_flatten_comma()
#> [1] "Merc 230 (22.8), Hornet 4 Drive (21.4), Merc 280 (19.2), Camaro Z28 (13.3), Lotus Europa (30.4)"

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0

An alternative with the magrittr exposition pipe %$% and stringr::str_glue:
mtcars %>% 
  head() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %$%
  str_glue("{car} ({mpg})") %>% 
  str_flatten_comma()

Output:
[1] "Mazda RX4 (21), Mazda RX4 Wag (21), Datsun 710 (22.8), Hornet 4 Drive (21.4), Hornet Sportabout (18.7), Valiant (18.1)"


And if it's not obvious: ... %$% paste0(car, " (", mpg, ")", collapse = ", ")

I would offer this option:
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  transmute(tmp = paste0(car, " (", mpg, ")")) %>% 
  pull %>% 
  paste0(collapse = ", ")

[1] "Fiat 128 (32.4), Merc 280C (17.8), Valiant (18.1), Lotus Europa (30.4), Cadillac Fleetwood (10.4)"

APPENDED
If you need to store df as in your question you may use %T>% from magrittr package with assign() call:
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %T>%
  assign("df", ., envir = .GlobalEnv) %>% 
  transmute(tmp = paste0(car, " (", mpg, ")")) %>% 
  pull %>% 
  paste0(collapse = ", ")


Three additional solutions similar to with():
Dot Notation in Curly Brackets
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(42)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %>% 
  { paste0(.$car, " (", .$mpg, ")", collapse = ", ") }
#> [1] "Chrysler Imperial (14.7), Hornet Sportabout (18.7), Mazda RX4 (21), Pontiac Firebird (19.2), Merc 280 (19.2)"

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0
Anonymous Function
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(42)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  {\(x) paste0(x$car, " (", x$mpg, ")", collapse = ", ")}()
#> [1] "Chrysler Imperial (14.7), Hornet Sportabout (18.7), Mazda RX4 (21), Pontiac Firebird (19.2), Merc 280 (19.2)"

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0
Custom Function
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(42)

my_fun <- function(x) paste0(x$car, " (", x$mpg, ")", collapse = ", ")

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  my_fun()
#> [1] "Chrysler Imperial (14.7), Hornet Sportabout (18.7), Mazda RX4 (21), Pontiac Firebird (19.2), Merc 280 (19.2)"

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0

If you need to capture the result
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78341333/11732165 stores the df whereas many others do not, you might find the latter more natural:
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  `<-`(df, .) %>%
  paste0(.$car, " (", .$mpg, ")", collapse = ", ")

since it just pipes to the standard assignment function.
